# What UTM like coordinate system is this?

Tags: coordinates, utm

I have this set of coordinates: `4622580.00000, 503749.00000`

They should roughly correlate with `51°01'39.4"N 13°44'44.2"E` in Dresden, Germany.

At first I thought they might be UTM, but that puts me off the coast of Somalia. Does anybody have an idea? Or maybe they are UTM but with special *options*? I am unfortunately not very knowledgeable with coordinate systems.

[image]

Comment: Which UTM zone did you use? 33 North?

Comment: It could also be a local coordinate system, too.  I am not familiar with German coordinate systems, but I wouldn't discount the possibility.

Comment: If you use those coordinates in UTM 33N, but *switch the easting and northing*, it will put you off the coast of Somalia. However, using the easting and northing correctly in that zone puts you just north of Naples.

Comment: where did you get that coordinates? GPS, Google Earth?, etc...

Comment: They could as well be local, I got them from the API of our municipal transport company. Any tips on how one would go to interpret these correctly? @nmpeterson Yes, that's what I used.

Comment: According to [this](http://rnd.ciit.net.pk/grass60_v1.2_en/node22.html), you may be looking at Gauß-Krüger (Gauss Kruger) coordinates.

Comment: That is still problematic.  The DHDN coordinate zones uses Gauß-Krüger and Zone 4 gives 4622564.6, 5656167.18 for the  coordinates provided in the map by the OP.  These DHDN4 coordinates match the location in the map, and the first coordinate is very close, which makes me wonder whether the second coordinate has been provided incorrectly (either by or to the OP).

Comment: @MappaGnosis That is remarkably close, very odd. But what I stated above is exactly what their API returns, I've checked multiple times. It'd be a shame if their data is off, but I really can't believe that.

Comment: Well, half of the coordinate is very close (which might be coincidental).  The second coordinate is an order of magnitude too small (which is why I wondered if it had been written down wrong... or maybe a false Northing has been incorporated).  As it comes from an API, can you get in touch with the people whose API it is and ask them what coordinate system they are using?

Answer (score 1):

So it's been figured out. Apparently it's a format called [MDV](http://data.linz.gv.at/katalog/linz_ag/linz_ag_linien/fahrplan/LINZ_AG_LINIEN_Schnittstelle_EFA_Koordinaten.pdf), which is an internal format used by the company providing this data. They nevertheless appear to be based on Gauß-Krüger coordinates, but only somewhat.

As not noticed by me previously, the API does offer options for returning WGS84 coordinates as well, which fortunately makes this question obsolete and makes for a lot easier handling of the data.